# Entity created whereas not asked in the code

Tags: php, symfony

I don't know why, the piece of code below is creating a new `Colle Entity ($colle)` after flush. I don't understand why. This is only a part of the code but I tried to `flush` right before it and if I do that, I still have the right `Colle entity`, the one given at first.
When I remove `flush`, The new entity is not created either. The new Colle entity is like a copy of the initial entity, with the same properties.

This code is in a loop and the new `Colle entity` is created only the first time.

```
private function gestionErreur($copies,$colle) {

   for($positionCopie=1;$positionCopie<sizeof( $copies )-1;$positionCopie++)
   {
      $user=$this->em->getRepository(Tutore::class)->findOneBy(['username'=>$copies[$positionCopie]['username']]);
      $passercolle = new PasserColle($colle, $user);
      $passercolle->setClassement(-1);
      $this->em->persist($passercolle);
      $this->em->flush();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you dont fetch `$colle` from database but create it in code it's created and saved. What you expect, I really don't understand. Provide full code please.

Comment: I edited my code. Problem is : I give `$colle` to the function and on the first loop, when I flush, `$colle` is not the initial object given but a new object with all the same properties as the initial one but with a new ID. 
After that, `$colle` doesn't change and stays the same

Comment: Try to `dump($colle);` right before for loop and then right before flush and let us know the result. There is no reason for the $colle to change itself.

Comment: So if $colle is new object it is saved after flush, is there anythink that you don't understand? Try to flush only $passercolle: `$this->em->flush($passercolle);`.

Comment: @HonzaRydrych Before `$this->em->flush()`, I get object Colle of Id 105 and after, I get object Colle of Id 185 which didn't exist before flushing.

@malcolm I also tried that and it has the same behavior. Something is happening with the first persisted PasserColle object because it's only when I persist this entity that a new Colle entity is created.

Comment: I also tried to `dump($passercolle->getColle())` before and after `flush()` and I get two different Colle objects. That's really weird.